# UIButton Image with PDF has full width image view

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm trying to build a radio-style like button (a circle with a dot on the left, and text next to
it on the right), pretty much like this:

[image]

I have 2 PDFs ([link to one of them](http://www.filedropper.com/radioticked)) containing images for selected and unselected radios. My code for the button is as follows:

```swift
let radioBtn = UIButton()
radioBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "radio", in: .module, compatibleWith: nil), for: .normal)
radioBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "radio_ticked", in: .module, compatibleWith: nil), for: .selected)
radioBtn.contentHorizontalAlignment = .leading
radioBtn.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
radioBtn.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 5, bottom: 0, right: 0)
radioBtn.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 0, bottom: 8, right: 0)
radioBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
radioBtn.contentVerticalAlignment = .center
radioBtn.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

The problem is that the UIImage stretches over the whole width (the blue part) and there is no space for thee text to show:

[image: ((UIImageView *)0x157019080)]

What I want to accomplish is the radio completely on the left, and then the text next to it with some inset. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your code is not setting a **Width** for your button. In that case, the button will set the width of its imageView to the size of the image -- with your `pdf`, that ends up being `510` pts wide.

So, couple options...

1. Use some scaling code to resize your image. If you're setting the button Height to 40, with 8-pts top and bottom insets, you need a `24x24` image.
2. Give your button a Width constraint, and calculate the imageView insets "on-the-fly."

Probably the easiest way to do that is with a `UIButton` subclass, such as this:

```
class RadioButton: UIButton {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {

        contentHorizontalAlignment = .leading

        // 8-pts inset "padding" on all 4 sides
        contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 8, bottom: 8, right: 8)

        // set title inset Left to content inset Left
        var insets: UIEdgeInsets = titleEdgeInsets
        insets.left = contentEdgeInsets.left
        titleEdgeInsets = insets

        // set images for .normal and .selected
        if let img = UIImage(named: "radio") {
            setImage(img, for: .normal)
        }
        
        if let img = UIImage(named: "radio_ticked") {
            setImage(img, for: .selected)
        }
        
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // make sure an image was set (otherwise, there is no imageView)
        if let imgView = imageView {
            // get height of imageView
            let h = imgView.frame.height
            // get current (default) image edge insets
            var insets: UIEdgeInsets = imageEdgeInsets
            // set inset Right to width of self minus imageView Height + Left and Right content insets
            insets.right = bounds.width - (h + contentEdgeInsets.left + contentEdgeInsets.right)
            // update image edge insets
            imageEdgeInsets = insets
        }
    }
}
```

example in use:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let radioBtn = RadioButton()
        
        // background color so we can see its frame
        radioBtn.backgroundColor = .red
        radioBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(radioBtn)

        // give it a 22-pt bold font
        radioBtn.titleLabel?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 22.0)
        
        // set the Title
        radioBtn.setTitle("Testing", for: [])

        // Height: 40
        radioBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        // Width: 240
        radioBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 240.0).isActive = true
        // centered in view
        radioBtn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        radioBtn.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this extensive answer, it works!

Comment: I just noticed this doesn't work on iOS 12 (and probably lower too). The edge insets calculated seem off.